# Replacing values in a data frames based on condition

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, if-statement, dplyr

*I want to convert values 0<x<9 & x<50.2 to NA.My data frame has the first five columns which do not have to have replaced, I only want to replace values in column 6 to column 60. I have tried to it in 2 steps as follows but, it also replaced values I dont intend to change*

`BdsDf[BdsDf > 50.2][6:60] <- NA; BdsDf[BdsDf < 9][6:60] <- NA`

Comment: `BdsDf[BdsDf[6:60] > 50.2, 6:60] <- NA` and the same for the other one.

Answer (score 0):

With `naniar`, you can use `replace_with_na_at` to select the specific columns and add the 2 conditions.

```
library(dplyr)
library(naniar)

BdsDf %>%
  replace_with_na_at(.vars = -1:5,
                     condition = ~ .x < 9 | .x > 50.2)
```

Or in base R,  you can do the following with the sample dataset. For your data, you would just change `6:8` to `6:60` (like with the commented out portion below).

```
BdsDf[,6:8][BdsDf[6:8] > 50.2 | BdsDf[6:8] < 9] <- NA
# BdsDf[,6:60][BdsDf[6:60] > 50.2 | BdsDf[6:60] < 9] <- NA
```

**Output**

```
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8
1  75 86 91 16  6 NA NA NA
2  84 68  8 85 19 NA 38 NA
3  18 52  5 17 59 NA 28 NA
4  97 86 45 17 31 NA NA 28
5  41 95 60 80 49 NA 24 NA
6  47 56 65 35 44 18 NA 19
7  29 46  3 22 36 15 NA 10
8  48 50 60 38 47 NA NA 35
9  91 20 50  5 24 40 47 19
10 85 84 15 71 96 NA NA 26
```

**Data**

```
BdsDf <- structure(list(X1 = c(75L, 84L, 18L, 97L, 41L, 47L, 29L, 48L, 
91L, 85L), X2 = c(86L, 68L, 52L, 86L, 95L, 56L, 46L, 50L, 20L, 
84L), X3 = c(91L, 8L, 5L, 45L, 60L, 65L, 3L, 60L, 50L, 15L), 
    X4 = c(16L, 85L, 17L, 17L, 80L, 35L, 22L, 38L, 5L, 71L), 
    X5 = c(6L, 19L, 59L, 31L, 49L, 44L, 36L, 47L, 24L, 96L), 
    X6 = c(66L, 0L, 84L, 3L, 84L, 18L, 15L, 60L, 40L, 67L), X7 = c(73L, 
    38L, 28L, 6L, 24L, 91L, 79L, 7L, 47L, 88L), X8 = c(92L, 57L, 
    66L, 28L, 85L, 19L, 10L, 35L, 19L, 26L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: Thank you the response AndrewGB. I am using R version 4.0.2, the 'nanair' package is not available. "> install.packages("nanair")
Installing package into ‘C:/R-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘nanair’ is not available (for R version 4.0.2)"

Comment: @magwabat It looks like you misspelled the name of the package (you reversed the i and a). It should be `install.packages("naniar")` to install it. If you still have trouble, then you can always try to install the dev version. `install.packages("remotes"); 
remotes::install_github("njtierney/naniar")`

Comment: @magwabat I've also added a simple base R way to do it as well, if you want to avoid  installing additional packages.

Comment: I have discovered that, instead of replacing values based on the entire data set, I need to replace using  values for each and every row (to change values for that row) . Replacement values are in row 59 and row 60. This loop coudntwork                 
                                                                                                                                            
 for (i in 6:nrow(BdsDf)) {
      if(BdsDf[i, ] > 0 & BdsDf[i, ] < BdsDf[, 60]){
      BdsDf[i, ] <- NA
    }
    {
      if(BdsDf[i, ] > BdsDf[, 59]){
        BdsDf[i, ] <- NA
      }
    }
  }

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
# test data
df = data.frame(lapply(1:60, function(x) {
  rnorm(100, 50, 25)
}))


df[,6:60][0 < df[,6:60] & df[,6:60] < 9 & df[,6:60] < 50.2] = NA
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Claudio. I tried the code and i got the following error message. ```Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, 0 < TodayFile[, 6:909] & TodayFile[,  : 
  unsupported matrix index in replacement```

Comment: It finally went through but it didnt change the values to NA.